# about select_related() caching

Tags: django, django-models

I am doing a select_related() queryset to prevent hit database innecesarily.
In my model I have:

```
class Item(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='items')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, null = True, blank = True) #django-cities
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null = True, blank = True) #django-cities

    def get_ubicacion_name(self):
        if self.region:
             return self.region
        else:
             return self.country

class Activity(models.Model)
    date = models.DateField()
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='items')
```

In my view:

```
ax = Activity.objects.select_related('item','item__region','item__country').all()[:40]
```

In my template:

```
{% for a in ax %}
    {{ a.date }} - {{ a.get_ubicacion_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

debug tool bar displays `43 queries in 53.87ms` because is hitting  `self.country` so `select_related('item','item_region','item_country')` is not working for this def?

In shell:

```
>>> ac = ax[0]
>>> dir(ac)
...... '_item_cache', .......
>>> dir(ac.item)
...... '_country_cache','_region_cache',.......
```

thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using just select_related()?  The point of the arguments is to limit which FKs the query follows, but you only have one to follow so it doesn't matter.  Additionally,you don't have to tell it to follow the further FK relationships (region and country) because select_related will automatically follow FKs as far as it can.  I'm not even sure select_related works with the __ "follow" syntax.

Comment: @Alex Kuhl: no, the OP's syntax is correct: select_related doesn't automatically follow relationships with `null=True`, which is the case for the region and country FKs.

Comment: Ah you're right, I missed the nulls in your definitions.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Can you try it in the shell? Get the `ax` queryset as you do in the view, then examine the first member with `dir`:

```
>>> ac = ax[0]
>>> dir(ac)
```

One of the attributes you should see is `_item_cache`, which is the way Django caches the ForeignKey lookup. Similarly, if you do `dir(ac.item)` you should see entries for `_region_cache` and `_country_cache`. If not, post the results here and hopefully we can debug further.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the cities are also related to regions and countries:

```
class City(models.Model):
# snip
region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
# snip

def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s, %s" % (self.name, self.region)
```

and when you call `get_ubicacion_name()` if the item has an associated city then the `City.__unicode__()` method gets called which generates at least one new query (to find the region) for each item.

I'd change your `select_related` as follows:

```
ax = Activity.objects.select_related(
    'item','item__region__city__country','item__country'
).all()[:40]
```

I haven't tested this but I think it should work.